# Does cache invalidation on dispatcher automatically happen when we activate a page in CQ author instance?

Tags: caching, aem, dispatcher

Hi have a small requirement related to a CQ page content modification and activation. However, I need to understand some basics before I work upon it. When a CQ author modifies a page content in author instance and activates it, it will be replicated into publish instance. However, will the cache invalidation for that page happen on dispatcher automatically after the page is published or do we have to manually clear the dispatcher cache by using some code?

help me understand this process

Comment: Configure the flush agents in your author after which the cache would be invalidated upon activation. Check http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/dispatcher/page_invalidate.html **Invalidating Dispatcher Cache from the Authoring Environment** on how to configure flush agents.

Answer (score 0):

As rakhi4110 already mentioned in his comment, you'll need a flush agent. But it has to be on the publish server to flush the dispatcher cache from the publisher. You can create the agent itself on author and also replicate it to the publish instance.
Not sure if there were many changes in the latest versions of the dispatcher, but just in case the direct link to the 5.6 documentation of the dispatcher:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/deploying/dispatcher/page_invalidate.html

And this is how it works: When you activate a page on the author instance, it gets replicated to the publish instance(s). There a create or a modify event is captured by the flush agent which then triggers the cache invalidation on the dispatcher. Depending on your configuration it will only flush the page which was activated or the branch the page is in or all html pages.